# Ionic 4 - CSS Global Max Page Width

Tags: css, ionic-framework, sass, shadow-dom

In Ionic 4, what is the best way to globally set the max page width or restrict the max width to a specific page/component?

Comment: Define global styles in app.scss. Define page/component-specific styles in the scss file for that page/component.

Comment: This is ionic 4, isn't it called global.scss now? I was hoping more for the actually styles/css needed

Comment: Sorry about that, you're right. Maybe try adding `.ion-page { max-width: X; }` to global.scss.

Comment: How about for a specific page in ionic 4?

Comment: Try adding a `max-width: X;` style to src/app/yourpage/yourpage.page.scss.